# Is there any message-based TCP socket library in .NET?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

While I'm a newbie in socket programming, as I was writing a simple tcp server-client program, I found the stream-based api is not that convenient to use.

My program is simply simple:

1. The client connects to a server
2. The server continuously send messages to client, in a unexpectable interval
3. The client receives message and do work according to the data contained in message

However, using the stream-based api, I have to:

- Define a **message delimiter / separator**
- Use a `while` loop to read data from stream
- Concat all bytes, try to find the **delimiter**
- If **delimiter** exists, split the data, extract the message

That's a lot work, even more than the entire logic of my program, so I'm wondering is there a library could do stuffs above for me, with such library I can program like this:

```
// Server
TcpListenerEx server = new TcpListenerEx();
TcpClientEx client = server.Accept();
client.SendMessage(new StringMessage("hello world"));

// Client
TcpClientEx client = new TcpClientEx();
client.Connect("localhost", 8989);
while (true) {
    IMessage message = client.ReadMesage();
    // Do work acording to message
}
```

Any suggestion would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: WCF would maybe fit the bill?

Comment: WCF dual mode is a good choice, but it is a little too "fat", and I'm not sure the final deploy environment could have a .NET 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedding a delimiter in a byte-stream is not as easy as it might look. You'd have to deal with the message accidentally containing the delimiter. This leads to lots of nasty detection and escaping code.

A very simple way to frame messages is to prepend a length-prefix. On the sender you serialize the message into a buffer, then write the length, then write the buffer. The receiver first reads 4 bytes to obtain the length. Then it reads the body.

This is not built into .NET, probably because every binary protocol is slightly different.

All of this is so simple that it is unlikely you will find a library. Such a protocol can be written in a few dozen lines. My recommendation is to just do it yourself.

If you want to structure your message, though, there *is* a great library: [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) (Google protocol buffers for .NET). It does message framing for you and also the serialization in a very sane way. It supports protocol versioning nicely.

Comment: Thanks to all responds, MSMQ, WCF, Thrift and SignalR are all excellent solutions, I have considered MSMQ as a better solution, however after this question we adjusted our design, now I have to write a nodejs based server and a .NET based client, with a javascript (browser bookmark) based **master client**, so the best solution seems to be write my own "protocol" since each language/framework cannot share a same library, thanks to this, a length-specified message is well suited to my project :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option for this could be MSMQ, which is a message queue (rather than a TCP/IP stream), and deals with messages rather than streams of bytes. MSMQ itself can use a variety of transports, including TCP/IP or WCF etc.

If you are only dealing with Windows (and since you mentioned .NET, that's not an unreasonable restriction), it's available on all versions from Windows 2000 on.

There is some good sample code out there that shows you basic ways of using it, as well as some of the more advanced stuff. It's simple enough that a sender basically builds up a message and queues it. Listeners receive complete messages.

It couldn't be much simpler, and if you want to do messaging on Windows it's one of the easiest ways of getting it going quickly.

Comment: Never connect MSMQ to a public network! It has wonderful low-latency and highly efficient throughput, but it MUST be secured behind a firewall, preferably with an active intrusion detection system. There are no MSMQ knobs you can turn that will make it secure. You simply have to hide it from the hackers, or you will be taken down. I would never allow any application to enable MSMQ on any of my machines.

Answer (score 1):

The official recommendation from Microsoft for such kind of client/server communication seems to be [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) now. There is a considerable amount of [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/).

However, if all endpoints are .NET applications, gRPC may be unnecessary heavy (not at runtime, but implementation wise). I was missing a really simple solution and ended up creating something myself, called [NetMessage](https://github.com/till-f/NetMessage). Bear in mind that I'm the author of that library, so my recommendation may be biased.

[NetMessage](https://github.com/till-f/NetMessage) supports custom C# classes as communication objects, ensures type safety and enforces request/response contracts. Once the connection is established, both client and server can initiate the communication (send messages or requests at any time). The receiver is notified by simple events when something was received.

This should give an idea how it works (for more details, see the [Readme](https://github.com/till-f/NetMessage/blob/main/README.md)):

```
// request packet
public class WeatherRequest : IRequest<WeatherResponse>
{
  public string City { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

// corresponding response packet
public class WeatherResponse
{
  public string Forecast { get; set; }
}

// and this is how to use it (compiler enforces correct types):
var response = await client.SendRequestAsync(new WeatherRequest { City = "Bonn" });
Console.WriteLine(response.Forecast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Thrift is another option, which is similar to WCF, but much simpler and does not bind to a certain .NET Framework.

http://thrift.apache.org/

It works fine for .NET 2, and even for Mono,

http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/

Answer (score 0):

I think the **[SignalR](http://signalr.net/)** Open Source framework should help.

Have a look on the [quickstarts samples](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) to see if it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you may want to consider using WebSockets.

Despite the name it's actually a more general protocol. It is essentially message oriented. Although messages may be split into frames, there are a lot of libraries which will reassemble these frames such that you'll receive the complete message.

Because of those libraries you can use WebSockets rather platform independent. Node, .Net, pure browser javascript - no problem.